# cannot understand can i republish it

Tags: console, playback

EASON FOR SUSPENSION: Alleged trademark infringement.

Google has been notified that aspects of your app, TAMIL WHATSAPP STICKERS -STICKER POTTI WASTICKERS, allegedly infringe upon the trademarks of others, and it has been removed from Google Play due to a violation of the Developer Program Policies.

All violations are tracked. Serious or repeated violations of any nature will result in the termination of your developer account, and investigation and possible termination of related Google accounts. If your account is terminated, payments will cease and Google may recover the proceeds of any past sales and the cost of any associated fees (such as chargebacks and payment transaction fees) from you.

You may contact WhatsApp at gp.enforcements.prod@gmail.com. If WhatsApp contacts us specifically authorizing your app to be re-published, and your app does not otherwise violate the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies, we will reinstate the app.

Please note that we have included a text copy of the Infringement Notice we received for your reference. If you have any further concerns about this issue, please address them directly to the complainant in the Infringement Notice provided below.

The Google Play Team

Text Copy of Infringement Notice:

country_residence: US
full_name: Alexis Meghrouni Rivas 
your_title: Director, Enforcement Strategies and Services
companyname: WhatsApp
contact_email_noprefill: enf.whatsapp.55116@enfappdetex.com
login_email: gp.enforcements.prod@gmail.com
address: 501 W. Grove Street
Boise
ID
83702
US
phone: +18722402777
trademark_relationship: Note: AppDetex is authorized by WhatsApp to 
facilitate the submission of and correspondence regarding complaints.
tm_work: WHATSAPP (stylized) (in color)
901609: BX
909148: BX
IR 1095940: EU
IR 1095940: WO

WHATS APP
3.02E+11: DE

WHATSAPP (in Korean characters)
450045582: KR

WHATSAPP
IR 1085539: AM
IR 1085539: AU
IR 1085539: AZ
IR 1085539: BH
IR 1085539: BY
IR 1085539: BW
831031522: BR
TMA838338: CA
952130: CL
952131: CL
IR 1085539: CN
437692: CO
437693: CO
213297: CR
213530: CR
IR 1085539: HR
189284: DO
464: EC
595: EC
IR 1085539: EG
21: SV
9986514: EU
IR 1085539: GH
191874: GT
196084: GT
117116: HN
127543: HN
301926874: HK
IR 1085539: IS
IDM000385654: ID
IDM000397555: ID
IR 1085539: IL
IR 1085539: JP
118722: JO
118723: JO
IR 1085539: KZ
IR 1085539: KE
100921: KW
136006: LB
57024: MO
57025: MO
IR 1085539: MK
IR 1085539: MG
2011051331: MY
2011051332: MY
1241811: MX
1241812: MX
IR 1085539: MD
842482: NZ
2013099494: NI
IR 1085539: NO
IR 1085539: OM
302143: PK
200843: PA
201630: PA
4569: PE
42011005919: PH
69181: QA
69182: QA
IR 1085539: RU
146924: SA
146925: SA
IR 1085539: SG
201111980: ZA
201111981: ZA
IR
android_app_url: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stickerapp.developers.whatsapp.sticker
trademark_explain: The app uses the trademarks, banners, badges and logos 
of WhatsApp without authorization.
tm_sworn_statement1: tm_good_faith
tm_sworn_statement2: tm_swear
NoticeToDeveloper: agree1
signature: Alexis Meghrouni Rivas 
signature_date: Mon, 25 Feb 2019
subject_lr_trademark: Your Request to Google
hidden_product: googleplay
geolocation: US
hidden_uraw:

:---- Automatically added fields ----:
Language: en
IIILanguage: en
country_code: US
auto-helpcenter-id: 1647639
auto-helpcenter-name: legal
auto-internal-helpcenter-name: legal
auto-full-url: 
https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_trademark?product=googleplay
auto-user-logged-in: true
auto-user-was-internal: false
IssueType: lr_trademark
form-id: lr_trademark
form: lr_trademark
subject-line-field-id: subject_lr_trademark
body-text-field-id:
AutoDetectedBrowser: HeadlessChrome 72.0.3617.0
AutoDetectedOS: Linux x86_64
MendelExperiments: 10800170,10800177
Form.support-content-visit-id: 636867285175836789-1244039086

Answer (score 0):

They say that your app is removed for the WhatsApp srickers used.
I will give you tip, from your app and it's description remove tge name WhatsApp and remove any WhatsApp logo n republish.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your description. Appdetex is a Mobile Apps brand and trade marks infringement monitoring firm. And Whatsapp also deals here with this company. If you make description of your app correct, then it will be able to be republish.